# How to fully clean hard disk before further use?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Is it possible to completely erase a corrupted internal Hard Drive and then use it as an external HD for extra storage with a HD enclosure case? Or would I face problems with it as an external? Any ideas - please let me know.

Comment: Is the drive corrupted or the data contents/structure?

Comment: I have a feeling it is just the drive and not the data. I believe it had something to do with the memory management.

Comment: Memory management in a drive? What?

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 9):

It is possible and easy. You did not provide information about your operating system, so I give instructions for Windows and for Linux.

**In Windows**

Use built-in *diskpart* tool. Start the command line window as administrator, and type:

`C:\ diskpart`

Then list available disks:

`DISKPART> list disk`

You will see a list of all available hard disks, including external ones. Determine disk to wipe-out number, note that disks are counted from 0. Let's say that disk to wipe-out has number 1. Select that disk:

`DISKPART> select disk 1`

and then wipe it out:

`DISKPART> clean all`

It may take hours, depending of disk's speed and size. At the end, exit *diskpart*:

`DISKPART> exit`

**In Linux**

Use *dd* command to overwrite disk with zeros. Let's assume that disk to clean is */dev/sdb*:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`

As in previous example, it may take quite a long time (few hours) to finish.

Be extremely careful! The *dd* command doesn't ask any questions, it works as ordered without any warning as soon as you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. A typo in disk name (i.e. *sda* instead of *sdb*) can cause disastrous consequences!

Note, that if your disk - as you suspect - has hardware malfunction, both methods will detect it and print some sort of error message. If cleaning is finished without errors, then it is safe to use disk as you need. The disk will work as external one in the proper USB disk case.

**PS**

Although *diskpart* command `clean` instead of `clean all` would take few seconds, it would clean only first and last megabyte of disk surface, missing any bad sectors that are out of those small cleaned parts. `clean all` puts zero in every single disk sector, so when some sector is damaged and unwritable, command will fail with error message. If you want to check whole disk - use `clean all`. If you want only to get rid of old MBR - go with simple `clean`.

The Linux *dd* method described above also fills whole drive with zeros. If you don't need such deep clean, then just clean first megabyte of disk by: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=1` - it takes only a second or two.

Comment: It's nice to see an answer that doesn't involve some third-party utility.  Also, just "clean" (not "clean all") will suffice in this case, and will take seconds instead of hours.

Comment: @Jason please see the Post Scriptum in my Answer.

Comment: Note that the dd command will destroy the content of the target disk "of=/dev/sdb" without warning.  Be careful.

Comment: @mgjk thank you, I edited my answer to include your point.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki I appreciate your reply, but I don't believe bad sector information survives a disk `clean`.  [According to Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415), `clean` overwrites the MBR, and MBR is where bad sector information is stored.  My understanding is that the purpose of `clean all` is for security--the data is much more difficult to recover.

Comment: @Jason when writing to some sector takes too long time it is considered damaged and remapped to sector on special spare surface of the disk. That surface is hidden and not reported as space available to use. This reallocation is done by hard disk firmware and this process is transparent for operating system as long as there is space available on the spare area. Only when there is no space left on the spare area, then disk reports bad sectors to operating system. To trigger this reallocation, write attempt to sector is required. So writing to whole drive is good method of detect bad sectors.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki I thought "grown defects" were stored in the MBR, and not the firmware, but I can't find a good source for this either way.

Comment: @Jason please see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sector_slipping - it is not exactly about spare area, but similar idea of remapping sectors when they are damaged.

Answer (score 1):

Another tool that works on just about any PC is [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) - "Darik's Boot and Nuke". This is a free utility. You download it as an ISO and burn it to a CD or put it on a bootable USB key. It lets you wipe a hard drive with your choice of data streams: All zeroes, a pseudorandom sequence, even DoD-approved wipe patterns. All zeroes is fastest and will serve for what you want.

I'm not saying that diskpart or dd are poor choices in any way! This is simply an alternative.

The idea in all cases is to wipe the partition info on the drive (the Master Boot Record, unless your drive is partitioned with GPT). This really only requires wiping block 0 (again, unless GPT). So you usually don't have to wipe the entire drive. As soon as the wipe utility has done virtually anything at all to the drive, the previous partition structure is gone and it will be seen as a completely unformatted drive. But since you suspect hardware issues with the drive it is a good idea to let it go ahead and wipe the whole thing, hence testing all blocks.

With any of these tools, just be darn sure to select the right drive! Do not count on any recovery being possible. If you're at all unsure, physically disconnect all drives other than the one you want to wipe, and use DBAN.

Comment: I disagree with the "just wipe MBR so you don't have to wipe the entire drive" idea, even for disk drives that aren't GPT partitioned. Data recovery software can recover data from an HDD with just the MBR sector wiped clean by searching for file signatures in the raw data. Some info here: http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/format-recovery-software/free-recover-raw-hard-drive.htm

Comment: It depends on your goal. The OP's stated goal (I thought) was simply to re-use a drive that apparently is corrupted in some way. All that is really necessary for that is to zero the existing partition information. But, you are correct, if the possibility of recovering old data from the drive is a concern... then definitely, wiping the whole thing is required.

Comment: Blancco bought DBAN from Darik and I would no longer consider it safe.  It's also completely unnecessary in this scenario.

Comment: The OP *did* say "fully clean" and "completely erase". Your Interpretation May Vary.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan include the use of hdd regenerator after the use of DBAN, for recovery of bad clusters, and it'll be a perfect answer.

Comment: I don't believe bad sectors *should* be "recovered". If they have once raised a noncorrectable error they should be spared and never trusted again. Just my opinion. 
(Verb. Sap.: The hard drive is completely unaware of anything called "clusters", that is an artifact of a file system.)

Comment: @jason I think all DBAN does is send a secure erase command to a drive. You can do the same thing from hdparm though it would not have a nice slick automated interface.

Comment: @Hennes: I haven't tried DBAN on an SSD, but on a HD, DBAN writes to every sector.

Comment: I never used it on a HDD. It should just try if the HDD supports the secure erase feature before falling back to the blunt overwrite whole drive methods. No idea if it does not do that well or if the drive just did not support the command.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **dd** with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M status=progress
```

Comment: While it is already said by @user322042 , the `status=progress` is a very useful addition.